# Return currently long running queries in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT status, total_elapsed_time, text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests CROSS APPLY 
     sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) 
WHERE status = 'running' AND 
      text like '%Insert%' AND 
      total_elapsed_time > '5'
```

To check if specific **running** query that contains '**Insert**' in the text and her **total_elapsed_time value** is more then 5ms.

But when i'm manually running the query is SSMS,
i'm always getting different output.

Don't i need to get a fixed output instead (which match the condition of my query of course..)?

Is there any other recommend way to check if there is a currently long running query on my SQL Server?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?  That will determine which DMV's you have available.  For starters, though, I would remove `status = 'running'` from your query.  Unless I'm mistaken, that will only be true when the query is actually running on the server - if it's waiting for resources or a time-slice from the server, it will have a status of "suspended".

Comment: Thanks Yogesh,

My Sql version is: Standard Edition (12.2.5000.0)

 But isnt DMV should be the same in every version of SQL?

And i need to check only the running queries..

Comment: No, @edwio - DMV's have evolved over the versions of SQL Server.

Comment: ^^ @edwio Definitely not always the case

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to exclude your own query from the resultset. Furthermore, in order to receive the same order, you should include an `ORDER BY`. Something like the following might do the trick:

```
SELECT STATUS
    ,total_elapsed_time
    ,TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests a
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) b
WHERE STATUS = 'running'
    AND TEXT LIKE '%Insert%'
    AND text NOT LIKE 'SELECT STATUS%TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME%sys.dm_exec_requests%'
    AND total_elapsed_time > '5'
ORDER BY a.start_time DESC
        ,a.statement_start_offset DESC
        ,a.statement_end_offset DESC
        ,total_elapsed_time DESC
```

Comment: Hey Tyron78's, 
I was trying to find a way to exclude my own query from the result, so thank you (i will be happy if you could explain how you did it..in the NOT LIKE section..)

The ordery by isn&amp;#39;t give a fixed output either, i'm allways getting diffrent outputs.. and i don't know if i can trust this query..

Comment: @edwio I simply put the main parts of your query into the `NOT LIKE`. However, having a look on my answer, I'd suggest to extend it to `AND text NOT LIKE 'SELECT STATUS%TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME%sys.dm_exec_requests%'`. So, how many queries do you have running at the same time? And differs the order between your checks or are certain queries simply terminated? Because if e.g. one query runs 5 seconds and the other one 10 seconds, this order will never change unless one query is terminated.

Comment: @edwio I extended the order by a little - please check, if this helps (besides checking if queries have been terminated)

Comment: @ is the b at the end of the CROSS APPLY Line: **CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) b**, is a typo?

Comment: No, it's an alias - you can give aliases to function results as well

Comment: you should put brackets around the "Where Status... OR...Status..." ;-)

Comment: 's I've modified my query: *WHERE STATUS = 'running' OR STATUS = 'suspended'*  *AND TEXT LIKE '%Insert into TEST_services_device%' * But Now i'm getting to many result, including my own query.. Furthermore, the other queries test output, isn't even including the text i'm searching..

Comment: You should try `(WHERE STATUS = 'running' OR STATUS = 'suspended') AND... `

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i was on a vacation.
I've tried your suggestion but i'm getting the following error: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword ''WHERE".**
.

Comment: Sorry - I mistyped the syntax. Should be `WHERE (STATUS...`instead of `(WHERE STATUS...`